# Efficiently making rows based on pairs of columns that don't apper in another table

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So I'm trying to model a basic recommended friend system based on user activity. In this model, people can join activities, and if two people aren't already friends and happen to join the same activity, thier recommendation score for eachother increases.

Most of my app uses Firebase, but for this system I'm trying to use BigQuery.

The current system I have in mind:

I would have this table to represnet friendships. Since its an undirected graph, A->B being in the table infers that B->A will also be in the table.

```
+-------+-------+--------------+
| User1 | User2 | TimeFriended |
+-------+-------+--------------+
| abc   | def   |        12345 |
| def   | abc   |        12345 |
| abc   | rft   |         3456 |
| ...   | ...   |          ... |
+-------+-------+--------------+
```

I also plan for activity participation to be stored like so:

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+------------+
| ActivityId | CreatorID | ParticipantID | TimeJoined |
+------------+-----------+---------------+------------+
| abc        | def       | eft           |      21234 |
| ...        | ...       | ...           |        ... |
+------------+---------- +---------------+------------+
```

Lastly, assume maybe there's a table that stores mutual activities for these recommended friends (not super important, but assume it looks like:)

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| User1 | User2 | ActivityID |
+-------+-------+------------+
| abc   | def   | eft        |
| ...   | ...   | ...        |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

So here's the query I want to run:

1. Get all the participants for a particular activity.
2. For each of these participants, get all the other participants that aren't their friend
3. Add that tuple of {participant, other non-friend participant} to the "mutual activites" table

So there are oviously a couple of ways to do this. I *could* make a simple BigQuery script with looping, but I'm not a fan of that because it'll result in a lot of scans and since BigQuery doesn't use indexes it won't scale well (in terms of cost).

I could also maybe use something like a subquery with `NOT EXISTS`, like something like `SELECT ParticipantID from activities WHERE activityID = x AND NOT EXISTS {something to show that there doesn't exist a friend relation}`,  but then its unclear how to make this work for every participant at one go. I'd be finee if I can come to a solution who's table scans scale linearly with the number of participants, but I have the premonition that even if I somehow get this to work, every NOT EXISTS will result in a full scan per participant pair, resulting in quadratic scaling.

There might be something I can do with joining, but I'm not sure.
Would love some thoughts and guidance on this. I'm not very used to SQL, especially complex queries like this.

PS: If any of y'all would like to suggest another serverless solution rather than BigQuery, go ahead please :)